# Call function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Here I have two functions: `updateTooltipContent` and `distance`.

When I try to call `distance(latt)` in `updateTooltipContent` it does not return any value. I cannot see why not

CODE:

```
function updateTooltipContent() {
    var fullt = $(this).width();
    var startt = $(this).position().left + 200;
    var endt = fullt + startt;
    var latt = $(this).attr("lat");
    return "Spending: " + formatTime(fullt) +  
     "</br>  Between:(" + formatTime(startt) + " and " + 
      formatTime(endt) + ") </br>" + distance(latt) + "km";
}
});

function distance(latt) {
    var bigArray = nArray();
    var dis = 0.00;
    for (var x = 0; x < bigArray.length; x++) {
        if (bigArray[x].lat == latt) {
            dis = bigArray[x].DISTANCE_FROM_PREVIOUS_OBJECT_LOCATION;
            break; // no point doing anymore loops as we've found the answer
        }
        return dis;
    }
}
```

This code work great but when I try to put some of code in function then wont to work:
WORKING CODE WITHOUT FUNCTION DISTANCE()

```
function updateTooltipContent() {
    var fullt = $(this).width();
    var startt = $( this ).position().left + 200;
    var endt = fullt + startt;
      var latt = $(this).attr("lat");
      var bigArray = nArray();
var distance = 0.00;

for(var x = 0; x < bigArray.length; x++)
{
    if(bigArray[x].lat == latt)
    {
        distance = bigArray[x].DISTANCE_FROM_PREVIOUS_OBJECT_LOCATION;
        break; // no point doing anymore loops as we've found the answer
    }        
}
      return "Spending: "+formatTime(fullt) + "</br>  Between:("+formatTime(startt) + " and " +formatTime(endt)+") </br>" + distance.toFixed(2) + "km";
    }
});
```

Comment: *" there is some error "* Do we have to guess the error or are you going to tell us about it? [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: yes fnction dont return any value, distance(latt) dont return any value

Comment: Is `bigArray.length` bigger than 0? Otherwise your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: how do you call `updateTooltipContent()`? what is `this` inside that function?

Comment: Let me get this strait. You want to call a jQuery function using JavaScript? Or do you want to call a JavaScript function from jQuery? Both of those are possible.

Comment: Formatting your code properly shows that you have an addition `});` in your code. Just saying. What is `nArray`? There is too much information missing to help you. Please provide more information and a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Open the Dev toolbar of your browser and check the console for javascript error. [To open dev toolbar, Press F12]

Comment: I think `updateTooltipContent` is a closure variable.. so it is not visible to `distance`

Comment: Maybe `bigArray[0].lat == latt`. In that case your loop breaks on the first iteration and it never reaches the return statement. You are also only doing one iteration at most, since you placed that return statement inside the loop. You probably want to place it AFTER the loop.

Comment: ok, nArray is function which retrn me array, I want to call with javascript, or jquery, $(this) is dom element on hover, and HOW updateTooltipContent is closure variable ?

Comment: in console there is no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once bigArray[x].lat == latt, statement break will be invoked, your for loop will be skipped immediately; since your return statement stays in the loop, of course nothing will return.

To fix this issue, just move your return statement out of the for loop.

Comment: WORK, THANKS, SO EASY